# how to access request.user in django modelform in admin

Tags: python, django

Wish to filter a dropdown list based on the currently logged in user in the model admin by overriding the changelist view. I am trying to filter the dropdown of categories belonging to the user of the department only

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['department','name']
    list_filter = ['department','name']

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        self.form = CategoryForm
        print dir(self.form)
        self.form.fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(
            name = request.user.customuser.department.name)
```

How can this be achieved? Using django 1.6.5

**ERROR**

```
type object 'CategoryForm' has no attribute 'fields'
```

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: It throws up the error: type object 'CategoryForm' has no attribute 'fields'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it is not a goot practice to alter base_fields of ModelForm class, but in this case class is generated on every request so it is OK.

```
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(CategoryAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(
                name=request.user.department.name)
        return form
```

Comment: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'CategoryForm' object is not callable

Comment: I think there is some kind of typo involved. How can it be that class is not callable?  Class is an instance of type, and it has a '__call__' method.
Please provide the exact code you use and python version.

Comment: python 2.7, djnago 1.6.5

Comment: I changed answer, now it should work fine. In general it is not a goot practice to alter base_fields of ModelForm class, but in this case class is generated on every request so it is OK.

Comment: Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Comment: remove changelist_view from CategoryAdmin or add "return super(CategoryForm, self).changelist_view( request, extra_context)" to the end of changelist_view method.

Comment: @AlexPolekha is there any particular reason to modify the `form.base_fields` instead of `form.fields`? From my understanding, [the form fields docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) and [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/68b8eda78864b78d1b8b2529ec119ec440f8458a/django/forms/forms.py#L81-L85) hinted that we should modify the `form.fields` instead of `form.base_fields`

Comment: @hashlash yes, you don't have access to `request` on `ModelForm.__init__()`.

Comment: @AlexPolekha I meant modifying the `form.fields` from the outside (not inside the `ModelForm.__init__()`). But I think now I understand that the `ModelAdmin.get_form()` is intended to handle the **form class** which doesn't have the `fields` attribute yet. Anyway, thanks for the response!

Comment: Modifying the `base_fields` directly (instead of the `fields`) attribute is the best we can do since `fields` only exists after the form is instantiated which is done in the middle of the `ModelAdmin._changeform_view()` function. So if we want to modify the `ModelForm.fields`, we should rewrite that whole function.